# Stack allocating intermediate objects in contructors

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++17

When a constructor allocates intermediate objects that need to be passed to other constructors with longer lifetimes, can the intermediate objects be stack-allocated?

For example, I have a class `Reader` that has various utilities build atop an `std::wistream` that has several constructors for various use cases:

- `Reader(std::unique_ptr<std::istream> bytestream)`
- `Reader(char buffer[], size_t count)`
- `Reader(const std::string str&)`

The only relevant member data that `Reader` has is:

`std::unique_ptr<std::wistream> m_character_stream`

> Note: wistream, not istream. The constructors construct the wistream in various ways depending on their argument types.

For example, the first constructor form, looks like this:

```
Reader::Reader(std::unique_ptr<std::istream> bytestream) {
    auto conversion = std::wbuffer_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>>(bytestream->rdbuf());

    m_character_stream = std::make_unique<std::wistream>(&conversion);
}
```

My questions are:

1. I guess since I'm being passed a `unique_ptr`, that I have no choice but to `std::move` it to some otherwise useless member variable to keep it alive until we're destructed? Even though the rest of my class will never use that variable directly, but only indirectly through `m_character_stream`?
2. The `conversion` object is stack-allocated. Is that going to be a problem? I assume that when the constructor returns, that this object will be deleted. Will that cause `std::wistream` to malfunction? Does that mean I have to store `conversion` as otherwise useless member data to keep it alive as well? If so, is there a common pattern or naming convention for useless member data that exist only to keep things alive?

Since I have multiple constructors, I'd rather not have a bunch of constructor-specific member data attached to my class since that data won't be initialized most of the time. This just all smells wrong, but this is my first `C++` project, so `move semantics`, `ownership semantics`, `smart pointers`, `RAII`, and all that crazy stuff is all pretty new to me and I'm trying to wrap my brain around it all.

I come from a `Java`/`Python`/`Go` background.

Comment: "*I guess since I'm being passed a unique_ptr, that I have no choice but to std::move it to some otherwise useless member variable to keep it alive until we're destructed?*" If your object cannot function unless that other object is still alive... it's not "useless". You are in fact storing what is effectively a pointer to the internals of the object. How is that "useless"?

Comment: This code shouldn't compile. `conversion` is a `std::streambuf`, but `wistream`'s constructor takes a `streambuf*`. You might have meant `std::make_unique<std::wistream>(&conversion);` (note the ampersand) - that should make the problem obvious, taking an address of a local variable and handing it to a long-lived object should immediately sound alarm bells.

Comment: @Igor You are correct. This code is simplified from my original code to make it easier to understand and I mistyped that part. I edited the question to correct that typo.

Comment: @NicolBolas I meant "otherwise useless", meaning "no use other than keeping the object alive". My class is carrying data that it never accesses. That variable will use up a name in my class's namespace which is never accessed aside from when its assigned in the constructor. I realize that keeping an object alive isn't useless, but that doesn't seem like it should be `Reader`'s responsibility. It's having to carry around `std::wistream`'s dependencies. In Java, for example, the references from `std::wistream` to its underlying data and objects would keep those objects from being GC'd for you.

Comment: If extra member variables bother you and you want to do a by-the-book OOP design, have a base class `WStreamHolder` with derived classes e.g. `WStreamOnIStreamHolder`. `Reader` would have `std::unique_ptr<WStreamHolder>` member variable, and its various constructors would instantiate the right derived classes, with those derived classes having the right member variables for each use case. As the saying goes, "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection."

Comment: @RobertLee: "*My class is carrying data that it never accesses.*" It is accessing it. It's using internal objects of that object. "*that doesn't seem like it should be Reader's responsibility.*" You only think that because you're used to garbage collected languages which take that responsibility away from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you have to keep `bytestream` alive and the typical way is storing it in a `unique_ptr` member variable.
2. Yes it is a problem that `m_character_stream` is going to use the pointer you pass beyond the lifetime of `conversion`.  So yes, make `conversion` a member variable.

C++ does not have garbage collection.  Lifetime management is absolutely essential when programming in C++.  Read about RAII.